# Show taxons instead of products at root url?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

just loosing ideas about proper way to display taxons instead of products in body of spree_application layout.

The `spree/home/index.html.erb` template renders `spree/shared/_products` but I would like to render `spree/taxons/show` instead, for each taxonomy.
No wonder, `spree/home/index.html.erb` miss taxonomies context so `render :template => 'spree/taxons/show'` would know nothing about `@taxon` .

Any idea how simply display taxons instead of products at the homepage, using spree/taxons/show view preferably ?

Comment: You should be able to create a new controller and setup a root for this. Spree is a Rails application and you can do anything you can do in Rails.

Answer (score 1):

You should override the `spree/home/index.html.erb` template in your application's views directory if you want to override the content of this page. As for preparing the content, I would recommend writing a decorator for the `HomeController` and overriding the `index` action, like this:

```
 class HomeController < Spree::StoreController
   def index
     # code goes here
   end
 end
```